# How can I open a new view from a background thread without knowing what the current/main-view is?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

From what I understand any new view that is opened needs to have a parent/super view.

I have a background thread that communicates with a server and according to the server's response it needs to popup an alert and in response to that alert it needs to bring up some UI. This can happen 'anywhere' within my App and so I find it hard to provide this new view with a parent/super view.

Is it possible to open this new view with no knowledge of what's currently being displayed? Is there a non-intrusive way to detect the current view and use that as the parent/super?

One of the targets is not to require anything from the Delegate and other views.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the currently visible view depends on the setup of the controllers, eg. whether you use a tab bar, navigation controller etc. I think the easiest way would be if your background thread sent a notification (using NSNotificationCenter) on the main thread whenever you need the UI changes to happen. The View Controllers can then subscribe to this notification and handle the UI changes.

Notifications are just one way of communication though, basically what you want is to have your model background thread somehow message the currently active view controller on your main thread. How you exactly go about this will largely depend on your application (see first sentence again).

Comment: I need to do this without adding code to the delegate/views/view-controllers, would that be possible?

Comment: It would be possible as long as you can get the instance of the currently visible window, but its not good design practice. MVC is there for a reason, only controllers should modify the displayed views otherwise you will end up with a ghetto and bugs that are extremely tough to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need a view, you can add it as a subview of your app delegate's window.

In your application delegate:

```
- (void) showView {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor ];
    [self.window addSubview:view];
    [view release];
}
```

Then, when you want to show the view:

```
MyAppDelegate *d = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[d showView];
```

You'll need a way to dismiss the view once you are done with it, you can use

```
[self removeFromSuperview]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to bring-up/dismiss this new view without adding code to the delegate? Ideally the 'background thread' could handle it alone, the question is whether that's possible.

Comment: Didn't try it, but maybe "[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:view];" works... You can give it a try.